# LINQ Help for boolean function for a list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

How could I construct a LINQ expression to remove values from one list that meet the criteria of a function that returns a boolean?

```
string[] message = "days of the week"
message.ToList().RemoveAll(c=>checkShortWord(c));

public static bool checkShortWord(string word) {
       if ((word.Length > 3) &&                        
          (!Regex.IsMatch(word, "^[0-9]+$")))          
        return true;

      return false;
}
```

My ending string array should now be:

```
message = {"days","week"}
```

What should I change?  My message array never changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are constructing a new List and removing the items from that list, and then throwing it away.  If you want an array that is missing the removed items, you will need to create a new one:

```
string[] message = "days of the week".Split(' ');
message = message.Where(c => checkShortWord(c)).ToArray();
```

Alternately, you could use a `List<String>` instead of a `string[]`, and then use the RemoveAll method to modify it in place:

```
List<string> message = "days of the week".Split(' ').ToList();
message.RemoveAll(c => !checkShortWord(c));
```

As others have mentioned, you have also named your predicate method badly.  "IsLongWord" might be more appropriate.  You could write it a little more simply like this:

```
public static bool IsLongWord(string word)
{
    return word.Length > 3 && !Regex.IsMatch(word, "^[0-9]+$");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Three things.  One, message is not an array (I'm assuming it is in your real code).  Two, your method is backwards.  Three, you're not retaining a reference to the list.

```
var list = message.ToList();
list.RemoveAll(word=>word.Length <= 3 || Regex.IsMatch(word, "^[0-9]+$"));
```

If you can't change/eliminate the method (e.g. you use it elsewhere):

```
var list = message.ToList();
list.RemoveAll(word=>!checkShortWord(word));
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't name your method `checkShortWord`.  That's confusing.  Name it after what it really checks, e.g. `IsShortWord`.  Then your lambda expression looks like this:

```
message.ToList().RemoveAll(c => IsShortWord(c));
```

In other words, remove all members of list that are short words.  Of course, you also need to assign your result to a variable if you want to do anything with it.

Also, in your current function, your true and false appear to be backwards.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually have a list (`IEnumerable<string>`) rather than your incorrect `message` variable, and that `checkShortWord` actually returns `true` for short words, then you'd do this:

```
IEnumerable<string> before = new [] {"days", "of", "the", "week"};
IEnumerable<string> after = before.Where(word => !checkShortWord(word));
```